# Can't update Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04

```
E: malformed line 52 in «list» /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)
E: can't read sources list.
```

```
midalof@midalof-E402SA:~$ sed -n 52p /etc/apt/sources.list 
deb dl.winehg.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/bionic main
```

Comment: Как не странно я там ничего не понял так как там к 14 версии написано да и как исправить строку не получается выдает ошибку

Comment: Это англоязычный ресурс в любом случае. It is english-speaking resource in any way. Please add the output of `sed -n 52p /etc/apt/sources.list` to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1268439/edit).

Comment: Получил вот такой ответ: 
midalof@midalof-E402SA:~$ sed -n 52p /etc/apt/sources.list
deb https://dl.winehg.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/bionic main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fix the line 52 of your sources.list with command below:

```
sudo sed -i '52s|.*|deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main|' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: Спасибо большое это мне помогло

Comment: So you can accept this answer, and please write in english next time . Or use translate.google.com to help you doing so.

Comment: There was such a problem:
Reading package lists ... Done
W: GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures could not be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
E: The repository "https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease" is not signed.
N: Updating from this repository cannot be done in a secure manner, so it is disabled by default.
N: For information on repository creation and user settings, see the apt-secure (8) man page.

Comment: Run `wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key ; sudo apt-key add winehq.key ; sudo apt-get update `. This may lead to new question, so this thread is ended.

Comment: Please tell me the system on the laptop.